# Run specific commands in PowerShell under different credentials?

Tags: powershell, cmd, credentials

I am trying to run a specific command line function in my PowerShell script. The catch is the command needs elevated permissions to be able to execute.

Here is a condensed example:

```
# PowerShell code...
query session /server:"SERVERNAME" #NEEDS ELEVATED PERMISSIONS
# More PowerShell code
```

The `query` command needs to be run under elevated permissions.

I have tried the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    query session /server:"SERVERNAME"
} -Credential get-credential
```

But this doesn't work because the `-ComputerName` parameter needs to be present when using a `-Credential` parameter. I want to be able to run this without using a remote server.

I know I can get around it by having the users start up PowerShell under their elevated account credentials, but I'd rather just prompt for credentials while the script runs and just run that single command under their administrator account credentials. Everything else the script does is fine under normal credentials.

Comment: Use `-Computername $Env:Computername` to run Invoke-Command on the local system.

Answer (score 0):

There are some add-ins for PowerShell, but I actually found the simplest way was to:

1. Sysinternals in regular command line
2. With the PSexec process, you can pass IP address, usermame, and password
3. Fiddle with it to a point you're happy
4. Create a batch file to then run from PowerShell if that is the desired deploy to environment
5. When creating the method, have it consume parameters if you want the call out to be dynamic and consume different usernames/passwords/IP addresses to log into
6. If the exec will always run on "computerA" using "loginA" and "pwA" then there is obviously no need to parameterize
7. *Sysinternals cannot be used to outright hack a terminal. The user of a remote exec must first have the same Sysinternals tools installed to the system  that is to accept remote executables, that tool must be opened once and given GUI-based approval to allow run on said system must be physically addressed.

Note: Any remote PSexec's using credentials will execute with the same level of permissions that the provided username/password is granted on that system.

Here is the link: ([PsExec v2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)). Although I recommend going a level or two up and downloading the entire toolbox.